# How to use a Label as a ProgressBar

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-controls

I have a problem with a project I'm doing.

I have a panel that contains 8 labels (Label 1, Label 2, etc...)

What I want to do is change a label into a progress bar with text.
This happens dynamically.

Note: It has to change back.

Can I do this ?

Also, I have to set the progress bar colors to red and orange when a quota is reached.

I tried:

```
Label1 = Progressbar1
Progressbar1.value = 75
```

But that doesn't work
duuh

Comment: That doesn't make sense... You could put the two control on the page, one on top of the other and have only one of them visible at a time.

Comment: is it posible to place 2 element on top of eachother when a label is docked??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`What I want to do is change a label into a progress bar with text.`  Doing so, it wont look like the standard progress bar with the animations.  To compensate this will use a gradient:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class LabeledMeter
    Inherits Label

    Public Property MinValue As Int32 = 0
    Public Property MaxValue As Int32 = 100
    Private mVal As Int32 = 1
    Private mValue As Double
    Public Property Value As Int32
        Get
            Return mVal
        End Get
        Set(value As Int32)

            If mVal <= MaxValue AndAlso mVal >= MinValue Then
                mVal = value
                mValue = mVal / MaxValue
                Me.Invalidate()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property StartColor As Color = Color.LimeGreen
    Public Property EndColor As Color = Color.Firebrick

    Private meter As Boolean = False
    Public Property MeterDisplay As Boolean
        Get
            Return meter
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If meter <> value Then
                meter = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        If MeterDisplay = False Then
            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
            Return
        End If

        ' fun and games
        Dim c2 As Color = EndColor
        'If mValue < 0.51 Then
        '    c2 = Color.Yellow
        'End If

        Dim rect = New Rectangle(0, 0,
                        Convert.ToInt32(Width * mValue), Height)
        Using br As New LinearGradientBrush(rect, StartColor, c2, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rect)
        End Using

        ' could draw the Text - specs are not clear
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, mValue.ToString("P1"), MyBase.Font, ClientRectangle, MyBase.ForeColor)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
        MyBase.AutoSize = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Notes**

- The `MeterDisplay` property toggles the metering or just standard label mode.
- `Value` changes the percentage filled.  It repaints only if `MeterDisplay` is True.
- Text versus XX% test display could be property driven.
- Lowering the alpha on the start color can sometimes provide good visuals

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm upvoting this in recognition of the effort, even though I am completely and utterly opposed to the idea of writing your own custom-control for a progress bar. It is always a better idea to use the system's progress bar control, not only for design elegance but also quality-of-implementation and accessibility concerns. If you're going to roll your own, you could *at least* use the system highlight colors like the classic-themed progress bar.